# Is it possible to use a dedicated connector to a standard enclosure?

Tags: motor, connector, three-phase, enclosure

I am a mechanical engineer updating a small machine at the factory that I work for.

Basically it is just a motor spinning an axis using a V-belt.

I need to put all the electrical components inside an enclosure.

What I would like to know if there is any problems of installing [this](https://www.se.com/es/es/product/PKF16G435/pratika-socket-screw-straight-16a-3p-+-n-+-e-380-415-v-ac-panel/?%3Frange=7644-tomas-industriales-pk&parent-subcategory-id=2510&filter=business-4-distribuci%C3%B3n-el%C3%A9ctrica-en-baja-tensi%C3%B3n&selected-node-id=12145870076) kind of connector on the lateral side of [this](https://www.se.com/es/es/product/NSYCRN33200P/puerta-lisa-de-spacial-crn-con-placa-de-montaje-h300xw300xd200-ip66-ik10-ral7035-/?%3Frange=2535-spacial-crn&parent-subcategory-id=88376&selected-node-id=12144272897) enclosure.

From what I understand, this connector should be used on dedicated enclosures.

It is a small custom machine and we rarely use it, so we need to move it around.

I think it is a good idea to be able to disconnect it without getting inside the enclosure and do it manually with the wires.

Comment: It may not maintain the IP rating, but otherwise I don't see any reason you couldn't mount that on a general purpose enclosure.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use a dedicated connector to an standard enclousure?

Yes, no other way to make it do anything useful, right? It'd just be a box you could store tea & sugar in.

The enclosure being "standard" doesn't mean you can not modify it. Usually to make it do anything useful you need to cut holes for connectors, controls, etc.

Now, if you want to maintain a given IP rating, use connector pairs with the same rating, and use appropriate sealing between the connector and the enclosure. Many connectors provide grooves with face-sealing O-rings to maintain their IP rating when installed on an enclosure. That helps reduce effort, otherwise you'd need to epoxy the connector down, or mill a groove in the side of the enclosure the connector is installed on. But that really depends on the needs of the application.

Often such enclosures will have connectors installed on the bottom face, when the enclosure is installed on a machine. Design so that normal ergonomic factors apply, e.g. a person working by the machine doesn't get snagged on the connector and the cable. Downward-facing connections help with that. On the other hand, if the connector is expected to be manipulated often, then a hard-to-access orientation may cause "fumbling" and connector damage. In such cases, a side- or top-access connector would work. Connectors on the front face (the hinged cover) work too, as long as there are other projections that will protect the connector from accidental contact and snagging.

> I think it is a good idea to be able to disconnect it without getting inside the enclosure and do it manually with the wires.

Cutting a hole for a cable gland isn't any "better" or "worse" than cutting a hole for a connector. The cable will still need to exit the enclosure *somehow* - through a hole. Might as well have a connector in that hole.

You could use that connector *inside* the enclosure, mounted on a bracket that the cable would plug into. Then the cable could enter the enclosure through a "all cables pass here" type of an opening. But there's no requirement for that, other than cost concerns. It may be easier to make a mounting bracket and stick it on a DIN rail inside, than to make too many mounting holes on the enclosure itself. But you'll probably have other controls for the machine on the enclosure as well, so this isn't like a big win or anything I don't think.

---

If you can, show us a CAD rendering of the exterior of the enclosure, with the door/cover closed, with all controls in place. I bet you that connector will look just fine on the side as long as it won't be prone to snagging.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have a number of boxes for storing tea & sugar and they are all very useful!